# How can i change backgroundColor for NavigationContainer in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

**React Native**

I have NavigationContainer and i want to change the background color to black.

i do first

```
<NavigationContainer style={{ backgroundColor: 'black' }}>
```

And second the code bellow

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer, DefaultTheme } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import First from './components/first'; // Import the First component
import Login from './components/login'; // Import the Login component

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const stackNavigatorOptions = {
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'black',
    },
  },
};

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="First" screenOptions={stackNavigatorOptions}>
        <Stack.Screen name="First" component={First} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I expect to change NavigationContainer Color from white to black.

Comment: does `<NavigationContainer style={{ backgroundColor: 'black' }}>` fail to add the background color? I'd assume this would work for you.

Comment: it doesn't work, i'm using iphone with expo the NavigationContainer background color is white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, i find the solution to change NavigationContainer background color.

```
    <Stack.Screen options={{
      title: 'My home',
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
      },
    }} name="First" component={First} />
```